# Entity is trying to insert a new record for a related table when I want it to update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I know this is an issue with me understanding how entity and database tables/relationships work.. I'm just trying to figure out where I am making a mistake.

I have a shopping cart table, with a foreign key to a related project table. I am trying to insert a new shopping cart record to the database, and by default entity is trying to insert a new project. However, I don't want a new project, I want the existing project updated in the database.

Here is the code for the insert and update of the shopping cart/project:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MakePayment(int? projectId)
{
    ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart()
    {
        ProjectId = projectId,
        Project = await _dbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.Id == projectId).Select(p => new Project()
        {
            AmountPaid = p.AmountPaid,
            RemainingBalance = p.RemainingBalance,
            OriginalPrice = p.OriginalPrice
        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync()
    };
    //set payment amount to remaining balance by default
    cart.PaymentAmount = cart.Project.RemainingBalance;

    return View(cart);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> MakePayment(ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
{
    //get user id of logged in user
    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    //if claim is null, that means we are not logged in
    if(claim != null)//claim should never be null, because we are using the Authorize Data Annotation
    {
        shoppingCart.AppUserId = claim.Value;

        //get the related project to update payment values
        var dbProject = await _dbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.Id == shoppingCart.ProjectId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if(dbProject != null)
        {
            dbProject.AmountPaid += shoppingCart.PaymentAmount;
            dbProject.RemainingBalance = dbProject.OriginalPrice - dbProject.AmountPaid;
        }
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    await _dbContext.ShoppingCarts.AddAsync(shoppingCart);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Here are my table models for the shopping cart and project tables (Code-first):

Shopping Cart table:

```
namespace FordWare.Models
{
    public class ShoppingCart
    {
#nullable disable
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        public string? AppUserId { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        [ValidateNever]
        public AppUser? AppUser { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        [ValidateNever]
        public Project? Project { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        public double? PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Project table:

```
namespace FordWare.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
#nullable disable
        [Required]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
#nullable disable
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        [ValidateNever]
        [DisplayName("Image")]
        public string? ImageURL { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        public string? LinkToProject { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        public double? OriginalPrice { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        public double? AmountPaid { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        public double? RemainingBalance { get; set; }
#nullable disable
        [Required]
        public string ServiceCSV { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        [DisplayName("Company")]
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        [ValidateNever]
        public Company? Company { get; set; }
#nullable disable
        [Required]
        public double EstimatedHours { get; set; }
#nullable disable
        [Required]
        public double EstimatedPrice { get; set; }
#nullable disable
        [Required]
        public DateTime TargetStartDate { get; set; }
#nullable disable
        [Required]
        public DateTime TargetCompletionDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when trying to Add a new shopping cart, then save changes in the database.. It is trying to insert a new project, and  the description column on projects is required... so it is throwing a null error... However, I don't want to insert a new project here... It is trying to do this I guess because of the Project navigation property on the ShoppingCart model:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Set the navigation property to `NULL`, so you use only the `ProjectId` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @progman has already stated in the comments, this is probably due to the `Project` property of the `ShoppingCart` being posted on your `MakePayment`method. [From the Entity Framework documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/explicit-tracking#inserting-new-entities):

> However, the Add methods don't just work on an individual entity. They actually start tracking an entire graph of related entities, putting them all to the Added state. For example, to insert a new blog and associated new posts

So if you post a `Project` on the `ShoppingCart` that does not exist on the database, Entity Framework will create a new one. And if the `Project` exists, your previous query will track it and my guess is that Entity Framework will navigate the newly attached `ShoppingCart` an edit the existing project properties with the values found on the `shoppingCart.Project`.

Maybe you can check [the change debugging information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/debug-views), it looks very promising for the kind of issue you want to debug.